# Why does this CGRectContainsPoint fail?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I guess I don't entirely understand the containsPoint method:

```
// test
CGRect compareRect = CGRectMake(-39, -62, 39, 62);
CGPoint comparePoint = CGPointMake(3, -27);
if( CGRectContainsPoint(compareRect, comparePoint) ) NSLog(@"works");
else NSLog(@"doesn't work");
```

When I plot it the point is inside the rectangle.  But it returns "doesn't work."

Comment: I doesn't contain that point =)

Comment: I was thinking in coordinates.  3 is > -39 && 3 < 39 && -27 > -62  && -27 < 62.  Been a long day for me.  =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3rd and 4th parameter for `CGRectMake` is width, height. So `compareRect` is from (-39, -62) to (0, 0) which does not contain (3, -27). It's a common mistake to think that the parameters are (x1, y1, x2, y2), but they are not. Actually they are (x, y, w, h).